# Count end points in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to be able to count "end points" in an XML file using XSL.
By endpoint I mean tag's with no children that contain data.

i.e.

```
<xmlsnippet> 
    <tag1>NOTENOUGHDAYS</tag1> 
    <tag2>INVALIDINPUTS</tag2> 
    <tag3> 
        <tag4> 
            <tag5>2</tag5> 
            <tag6>1</tag6> 
        </tag4> 
    </tag3> 
</xmlsnippet>
```

This XML should return 4 as there are 4 "end points"

Comment: Do you means nodes that have no child node? We also need to know what language you are wanting to use, else you will get a loose pseudo code answer.

Comment: Using XSL.  The XML format is quite loose, so I want to count anything that has no child nodes but may contain data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(//*[not(*) and normalize-space() != ''])" />
</xsl:template>
```

This recurses the entire XML tree via the descendant axis (`//`), looks at all element nodes (`*`) that have no child element nodes (`not(*)`) and contain data other than whitespace (`normalize-space() != ''`).

The resulting node-set is counted (and returns 4 in your case).

Comment: This looks good but the XML I posted is just a snippet so I need to call something like `select="count(//ParentTag/xmlsnippet/*[not(*) and normalize-space() != ''])"` - this returns 2 not 4.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aha, I used this and it worked `select="count(ParentTag/xmlsnippet//*[not(*) and normalize-space() != ''])"`

Answer (score 3):

`*[not(*)]` is used for elements that has no children elements.

edit: for counting them just use `count(elements)`

Comment: How do I do this recursively?

Answer (score 2):

Try:-

```
 <xsl:variable name="numOfLeafNodes" select="count(//*[not(*)])" />
```

this will tell you how many leaf nodes are found in the whole xml being transformed.  Use:-

```
 <xsl:variable name="numOfLeafNodes" select="count(.//*[not(*)])" />
```

to find the count of leaf nodes that are descendents of the current context node.

Comment: If I do this   `<xsl:variable name="numOfLeafNodes" select="count(ParentTag/xmlsnippet/*[not(*)])" />` then it returns 2 not 4.

Comment: @Chris: Indeed, but this would return 4: `count(ParentTag/xmlsnippet//*[not(*)])` note the `//` to which is a short-cut for `descendents::` axis.  Also noticed I had missed out the actual count function itself.